# Bind TimePicker & DatePicker - MVVMCross (Mono For Android)

Tags: android, datepicker, xamarin.android, timepicker, mvvmcross

How to bind a Time - & /DatePicker with MVVMCross in Mono For Android?

```
  <TimePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <DatePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And what are the types of the Properties behind? For Date, probably **DateTime** and for the TimePicker? Or do we have here a Property *foreach* Number, for Example for Date: Year (INT), Month (INT) and Day (INT) = 3 Properties?

Stuck at this one and didn't find any examples..

Help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DatePicker API from Android is pretty disgusting...

However, binding it should be pretty easy :)

What I would do is to add a custom control and a custom binding.

---

For some help on Custom Droid controls, see

- [How to create view's actions listener for MvxItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934654/how-to-create-views-actions-listener-for-mvxitemtemplate)
- take a look at http://github.com/CheeseBaron/ repo - he does loads of great custom controls

For some other questions about Custom Bindings, see

- Custom Favorites Button Binding - [MVVMCross Bindings in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495137/mvvmcross-bindings-in-android)
- Custom binding for text color - [In MvvmCross how do I do custom bind properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700445/in-mvvmcross-how-do-i-do-custom-bind-properties)
- Two way bindings for integers - [MvvmCross Monotouch C# - Binding Int Property - Mode: TwoWay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231624/mvvmcross-monotouch-c-sharp-binding-int-property-mode-twoway)
- Custom binding for a Touch event - [mvvmcross touch command binding in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815893/mvvmcross-touch-command-binding-in-android)

and other links from http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/p/mvvmcross-quicklist.html

---

The Android `DatePicker` API was clearly written by Kermit during some downtime, so for the `DatePicker`, I would probably suggest is that you implement an `EmiDatePicker` that inherits from `DatePicker` and tidies up the API.

This can provide a single property and a single event:

```
   private bool _initialised;

   public DateTime Value
   {
      get 
      {
         return new DateTime(Year, Month.ToCLRMonthNumber(), DayOfMonth);
      }
      set
      {
         if (_initialised)
         {
             UpdateDate(value.Year, value.Month.ToJavaMonthNumber(), value.DayOfMonth);
         }
         else
         {
             _initialised = true;
             Init(value.Year, value.Month.ToJavaMonthNumber(), value.DayOfMonth, new EmiListener(this));
         }
      }
   }

   public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
```

where:

- `ToJavaMonthNumber`, `ToCLRMonthNumber` are workarounds for +1, -1 fixes - see [MonthDisplayHelper.NumberOfDaysInMonth returning incorrect value in MonoDroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754025/monthdisplayhelper-numberofdaysinmonth-returning-incorrect-value-in-monodroid/14755749#14755749)
- EmiListener is a simple implementation of `IOnDateChangeListener` to fire ValueChanged - something like:

  ```
  public class EmiListener : Java.Lang.Object, DatePicker.IOnDateChangedListener
  {
      private EmiDatePicker _datePicker;

      public EmiListener(EmiDatePicker datePicker)
      {
          _datePicker = datePicker;
      }

      public void OnDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
      {
          _datePicker.InternalSetValueAndRaiseChanged(new DateTime(year, monthOfYear.ToCLRMonth(), dayOfMonth));
      }
  }
  ```

With this done... then the next code step would be to add a binding - this would be simple:

```
public class EmiDatePickerValueTargetBinding : MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding<EmiDatePicker>
{
    public EmiDatePickerValueTargetBinding(object target, PropertyInfo targetPropertyInfo)
        : base(target, targetPropertyInfo)
    {
        var datePicker = View;
        if (datePicker == null)
        {
            MvxBindingTrace.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Error, "Error - datePicker is null in EmiDatePickerValueTargetBinding");
        }
        else
        {
            datePicker.ValueChanged += DatePickerOnValueChanged;
        }
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.TwoWay; }
    }

    private void DatePickerOnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        FireValueChanged(View.Value);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            var datePicker = View;
            if (datePicker != null)
            {
                datePicker.ValueChanged -= DatePickerOnValueChanged;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to register this binding, just add it in your app's setup class:

```
    protected override void FillTargetFactories(Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Interfaces.Bindings.Target.Construction.IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxSimplePropertyInfoTargetBindingFactory(
                                     typeof (EmiDatePickerValueTargetBinding), typeof (EmiDatePicker), "Value"));

        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
    }
```

---

At this point, you can finally just use an EmiDatePicker in your XML - although to save on typing I'd recommend using an XML abbreviation - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/abbreviated-namespaces-for-your-custom.html

---

To do TimePicker... same again, but I'll leave that to you...

---

There will be typos in the above code - please do edit it to correct it.

If this code works... and since it is a lot of 'mechanical code', I would love to see it open-sourced (maybe even pushed back to MvvmCross)

Comment: Hi Stuart! Thx for the answer.. I'm trying to implement your solution. There's a problem in the second code. datePicker doesn't have a method `InternalSetValueAndRaiseChanged`..

Comment: It took me now the whole day to implement DatePicker and TimePicker.. there where lots of problems, finally solved it. I created a new Project for this (referencing to my main project). If you want I can send you the project as I have not lot of time to implement that in your libraries and make it opensource public.

Comment: Yes please - if you can include some kind of 'I'm releasing this to you ms-pl' or 'creative commons' that would help.