# suggestions how to achieve DatePickerDialog equivalent using mvvmcross & monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Currently have a Droid app implemented that in response to a button press pops up a DatePickerDialog.
As this must be a common use case does anyone have any suggestions how to achieve something similar with Touch?

Not sure if an AlertView can be used & if so how or what would be a suitable approach...

A pointer to an existing sample or project that does something similar would be appreciated.

TIA

Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming my UI designers agree (sometimes they like to do things differently)... I'd use a `UIDatePicker` - see

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html
- http://jsasitorn.com/2010/06/iphone-uidatepicker-tutorial/ (Warning - ObjC!)

---

As a fairly experience MonoTouch and MvvmCross dev I would do this by:

- create a custom `UIView` (maybe subclassing `UIButton` or `UILabel`) for my on-screen display
- inside that custom `UIView` when edit is needed, I would use a `UIDatePicker` with code like that inside https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/CrossUI/CrossUI.Touch/Dialog/Elements/DateTimeElement.cs
- for MvvmCross data-binding I would expose a `public DateTime Value {get;set;}` property and a `public event EventHandler ValueChanged` event
- to make that data-binding work I would then add some custom binding during my MvvmCross `Setup` - very similar to how it's now in this Droid question - [Bind TimePicker & DatePicker - MVVMCross (Mono For Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829521/bind-timepicker-datepicker-mvvmcross-mono-for-android)
- use that custom `UIView` in my 'page' with two-way binding on `Value`

---

If I were in more of a hurry though, I might instead:

- dump a button on the screen and bind it's Title to the ViewModel DateTime
- use code-behind in my 'page' `UIViewController` to hook up the button `TouchUpInside` to some code to show a `UIDatePicker`
- use code-behind to respond to `UIDatePicker` events in order to set properties back in the ViewModel

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply.. in this case I might have to use the quick option..